Real Estate near High Tech companies could fetch 25% annual compound rate?
I was thinking that it seems the real estate near some Fortune 5 or Fortune 50 companies (such as Oracle Corp), the houses near the lagoon with 4 bedrooms were going at US$450k in 1995.  Today, every one of them are at least $2.5M.
If I use the formula:
(2500000 / 450000.0) ** (1 / (2024 - 1995.0))
(with ** meaning to the power of), that will give me 1.0609141904768202.
So that means for the past 30 years, the rate of the price of the house increasing was 6% on average (compounding rate).
So I thought about, how is real estate near high tech companies compared to high tech companies themselves.
If I invest in one single company, it could go south some day. If I invest in QQQ, the Nasdaq top 100 companies that are not financial ones, so mostly high tech, then it is 10% increase per year for the past 30 years.
And I never thought getting 10% is so difficult.
Now, however, if I have faith in high tech for the next 25 or 30 years, then I can assume people can in general afford a 5% increase in real estate price nearby.  If one company (like Oracle) cannot make it big, the Facebook or Google nearby can make it big anyway, so people in general will "fight for" the houses nearby. (within 20 minutes of driving, I think).
So with a 5% increase in mind, if I just put down 20% down payment, that means my leverage is really 5x, and then means I can get 25% annually and compounding?
But maybe the problem is about scaling: I cannot buy 6 or 9 or 12 houses without driving myself crazy.  However, even if I can just scale it to 3 or 4 houses, at 25% rate, that will mean, let's say 3.5 houses x $2.5M today, which is $8.75M , and that will be quite enough for retirement.
Actually, if I can scale it consistently at 25% per year, that will mean, starting with $100k,
100000 * 1.25 ** 30

which is $80M after 30 years. But I think it is the problem of scaling that limited the process, but regardless, it is much better than QQQ, which is
100000 * 1.10 ** 30

and that is only $1.7M today.
From $100k to $8.75M today, it is
(8.75 / 0.1) ** (1 / (2024 - 1995.0))

which is 1.1667177226608754, so that means I am getting 16.67% per year. (so if not 25%, then 16.67%, which can still yield a much better result than 10%).
Is that thinking correct?

Unlike simply owning stock, owning real estate comes with continuing out of pocket costs. You have to pay property taxes and insurance every year, and you also have to cover maintenance costs. New roofs are expensive and you have to have one every 15-20 years. You also need to have the cash flow to cover all those interest payments. I don't see anywhere where you are allowing for the interest you will have to pay on your real estate loans. A plan doesn't consist of just figuring out what an amazing amount you can make if everything goes well.

Also remember that companies sometimes fail, which can result in a deep plunge in real estate values. Consider the rust belt.

Interest costs. Maintainable costs. Insurance costs. Real estate taxes. The value of your time managing the rental property or paying someone to do it Legal costs as a landlord See other answers about real estate; it can be a profitable business, but it is very much a business, with a lot of work and hassle and expense involved which has to be subtracted from the gross income to yield real profit, and significant risk of loss. Run all the numbers.

When we all stopped having Kodak moments, Rochester, NY became famous for "affordable housing". No one saw it coming. Which icon of industry is next on the list of has-beens? Get out your crystal ball.

There were some VERY big falls in the last 10 years... BlackBerry, Nortel, Cisco, etc. The list will simply grow and nobody would really know who is next. Microsoft was pretty bad when Steve Ballmer was at the helm but it has more or less recovered since.

You're thinking about it all wrong. The prices around the Oracle headquarters increased not because of Oracle per se, but because of the supply and demand pressures. Oracle has been headquartered in Redwood City, California, throughout the period you're describing (they relocated the "headquarters" to their Austin, TX, office in 2020). Facebook (Meta) is headquartered in Menlo Park, CA, and Google (Alphabet) in Mountain View, CA. Look at the map: all the three places are on the peninsula of the San Francisco Bay Area. This is a very limited area in terms of housing availability, with no available lands for expansion and the lands available are almost fully utilized.
The Silicon Valley came to be where it came to be because of several factors that all together made it a great location, but land availability for housing development was not one of them.
Regardless, your math is wrong:

So with a 5% increase in mind, if I just put down 20% down payment, that means my leverage is really 5x, and then means I can get 25% annually and compounding?

No, because you're paying down the 80% loan. So you're paying into more equity (reducing the leverage) and accumulating interest, taxes, and depreciation expense along the way. You're assuming they'll "pay for themselves" through rent, but that's not an entirely correct assumption. Many times, mortgaged rental properties, even with positive cash-flow, will be losing money. In California specifically you may run into issues like tenant protection laws, rent control, eviction difficulties, sharply rising costs of maintenance and repair, etc.

proving somebody wrong on the Internet can be a joy. Proving somebody "all wrong" must be supreme joy. I never said it is due to Oracle "per se". I mentioned it is due to demand from all over the area: from people who work at Menlo Park (Facebook) and from people who work at Mountain View (Google). And of course people who work at San Mateo and Palo Alto as well. You have to pay for mortgage interest, but I know some people needing to pay some cash towards the mortgage, but after a few years or a bit longer, the rent increased so much that they are positive in terms of cash flow

by the way, depreciating expense is not an "expense". It is a way to reduce tax. Think of Amazon who buys up warehouses and land to claim "depreciating expenses" to pay less tax (earning goes to $0.01, and people say PE was "high"). All that "expenses" turned into warehouses and land that increased so much in value

Depreciation expense represents... depreciation. Loss of value of your asset. Because you need to make additional investments over time for your real estate to remain valuable. It's not "way to reduce tax", it's governments' recognizing that the capital asset you own will necessarily lose value over time. I'm glad to have brought you joy. Good luck with your investments. Although, personally, I'd prefer literally anywhere else in the US over California for real estate investments. Let's talk after the first time you need to evict someone.

Some things you might want to consider:

You've only looked at the capital appreciation of the asset. Let's assume you have an interest only mortgage for simplicity. You have income (rent), for the period where there is no void (ie where the there is no tenant paying you), net possibly of bad debt. And expenditure: interest, cost of keeping the house(s) in repair, possibly property taxes. And cost of management (either done professionally or yourself). Now if rent exceeds costs, this might make your argument stronger - but it might be less than costs. The good news is that the rent will (probably) increase along with capital value (assuming rental yield remains constant).

Back to that loan. At least in the UK you can get interest only mortgages for rental properties. That's fine, you pay back your principal at the end of the period by selling the property, and your calculation is correct. If you pay the money back during the period, this will decrease your leveraged return (but reduce your risk).

I think this is the key issue: you identify an investment opportunity you could have taken 30 years ago. Will the next 30 years be the same? There's a sort of selection bias going on here as if you'd picked (eg) "second tier Arizona commercial property" I bet your numbers would have been far less exciting - but you wouldn't immediately have thought of that because it's CA property prices people are talking about. It's a bit like saying "had I invested in XYZ tech company at IPO which is now worth 100 times as much" - you would not immediately have thought of all the other tech companies that have gone bust. Many things could happen over the next 30 years: we could all work remotely more; tech companies could cease to be concentrated in the valley; tech could become "humdrum" and have fewer employees per $m revenue. What you are describing is a sort of indirect bet on tech. Yes it has leverage (which adds risk as well as return), but you could probably by some long dated QQQ options, or a QQQ margin trade if you want leverage. I'm not criticising your idea here - I think it's a reasonable investment strategy actually (and buy-to-let in the UK goes through periods of being super fashionable) - but it's not a dead cert. The question is "what is the risk adjusted rate of return?"


